# Make property optional or required based on condition with generic type

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
    const controlConfig = <T extends 'input' | 'button'>(config: Config<T>): Config<T> => config;

    interface Config<TYPE extends 'input' | 'button'> {
        type: TYPE;
        label: string;
        popover?: string;
        inputPlaceholder: TYPE extends 'input' ? string : never;
        key: string;
    }
    const config: Config<'input' | 'button'>[][] = [
        [
            controlConfig({
                type: 'button',
                label: 'user',
                popover: 'ID',
                key: 'user',
            }),
        ],
    ];
```

TS2345: Argument of type '{ type: "button"; label: string; popover: string; key: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Config<"button">'.   Property 'inputPlaceholder' is missing in type '{ type: "button"; label: string; popover: string; key: string; }' but required in type 'Config<"button">'

If there is no simple solution or shoud prefer use a type alias, why it's not add in typescript something like making propery optional in condition?

Comment: You should probably be using a discriminated union for this. https://tsplay.dev/wO20EW

Comment: So the question is "why isn't this already part of TS"?  If so then it's because it hasn't been implemented; there is at least one open feature request for this, see [ms/TS#44261](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44261).  For now it's not part of the language so you can't use an interface for this (it either has to be a generic type alias or a discriminated union). Does that fully address the question? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The type `'input' | 'button'` does extend the type `'input'`, so all of the objects in `Config<'input' | 'button'>[][]` will have a `type` property of type `'input' | 'button'` *and* must have an `inputPlaceholder` property of type `string`.

What you want instead is a union of objects, discriminated by `type`: `(Config<'input'> | Config<'button'>)[][]`.

I would however recommend not to use a generic at all, but rather define individual types and their union explictly

```
interface BaseConfig {
    // type: 'input' | 'button'; - can be defined but is not necessary
    label: string;
    key: string;
    popover?: string;
}
interface InputConfig extends BaseConfig {
    type: 'input';
    inputPlaceholder: string;
}
interface ButtonConfig extends BaseConfig {
    type: 'button';
}
type Config = InputConfig | ButtonConfig;
```

then use `Config[][]`.